# ToListAsync() mocking always returns 0 count

Tags: moq

I am trying to unit test an service operation which uses .ToListAsync() function for returning a list. The fake mock of this function always returns count 0.

Can someone please help me to understand why this is happening.

Comment: Is the method virtual? Without code there are many similar questions I could ask without getting the big picture. Could you please provide the relevant code for the unit test and class being tested?

Comment: I have resolved it. I wasn’t setting valid id while acting on the operation.

Comment: Feel free to close the question now. Thanks.

Comment: I don't have enough rep to do that I'm afraid, best you close it yourself.

Comment: I see a option to delete, share but no option to close. Lets not worry for that.